# How do you bold specific text in a PDF form field *and then flatten the form* using iTextSharp?

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, rtf

Given a PDF form with fields already specified, I want to be able to put something like this in one of the form fields:

> Rodrigo, you are **NOT** the father!

Using iTextSharp, I can accomplish this (albeit a bit painstakingly) using Rich Text values and passing in XML representing the content with the appropriate bold markup, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412527/15486).

However, according to that same answer (and my firsthand experience), you cannot lock+flatten the form (to prevent further editing) after you have done this. Unfortunately, that is also necessary in this case.

The author of the [previously-mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412527/15486) mentions that this can possibly be worked around by "[having Javascript] that resets the field value when the form its opened to force Acrobat/Reader to build the appearance[s] for you."

**How do you add Javascript code to a PDF (preferably via iTextSharp itself, although we *may* be able to do it on the back-end in the file itself) such that it executes when the form is opened to force the PDF reader to build appearances for you?**

Moreover, will this allow us to not have to say `GenerateAppearances = false` and therefore allow us to lock and flatten the form?

If not, **is there something other than iTextSharp that will allow us to make certain words in a form field bold but also lock and flatten the form to prevent future editing once we're done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out there is a way to accomplish this goal, though not via any particularly elegant means (that I know of).

The way you do it is by using iTextSharp to *write a text field directly over the existing form field*.

The main caveat here is that the pdf ceases to become a form, basically, so if you ever need to *read* the contents of the form fields, you're hosed.

On the other hand, if the form fields are basically being used as a simple guide to help tell iTextSharp where to put text on the pdf (and exist for output only), then this might just work.

```
using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(outputpath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
{
    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, filestream);

    var acroFields = stamper.AcroFields;

    string fieldName = "Field Name";
    var fieldPositions = acroFields.GetFieldPositions(fieldName);

    var helveticaBold = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 14);
    var helveticaRegular = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 14);

    List<Chunk> chunks = new List<Chunk>();

    chunks.Add(new Chunk("Rodrigo, you are ", helveticaRegular));
    chunks.Add(new Chunk("NOT", helveticaBold));
    chunks.Add(new Chunk(" the father!", helveticaRegular));

    Phrase currentPhrase = new Phrase();

    foreach (Chunk chunk in chunks)
    {
        currentPhrase.Add(chunk);
    }

    foreach (var currentPosition in fieldPositions)
    {
        PdfContentByte currentCanvas = stamper.GetOverContent(currentPosition.page);

        ColumnText currentColumnText = new ColumnText(currentCanvas);

        currentColumnText.SetSimpleColumn(currentPhrase, currentPosition.position.Left,
                                          currentPosition.position.Bottom, currentPosition.position.Right,
                                          currentPosition.position.Top, 13, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        currentColumnText.Go();
    }

    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
    stamper.Close();
}
```