# iTextSharp SetField method

Tags: itext

Is it possible to call `SetField` and have some parts of the text BOLD?

I'd like to set some of the text Bolded.

For example, using a HTML bold tag for illustration purposes:

I'd like to do something like:

```
AcroFields testForm = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

testForm.SetField("PDFFieldSubjectText", "This is <b>bold</b> text");
```

Comment: I don't know if iTextSharp has easier support for this yet but see this for way that you can do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4412527/231316