# underline portion of text using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, itext

I have an application that uses itextsharp to fill PDF form fields.

One of these fields has some text with tags. For example:

```
<U>This text should be underlined</>.
```

I'd like that the text closed in .. has to be underlined.

How could I do that?

How could I approch it with HTMLWorker for example?

Here's the portion of code where I write my description:

```
for (int i = 0; i < linesDescription.Count; i++)
{
         int count = linesDescription[i].Count();
         int countTrim = linesDescription[i].Trim().Count();
         Chunk cnk = new Chunk(linesDescription[i] + GeneralPurpose.ReturnChar, TextStyle);

         if (firstOpe && i > MaxLinePerPage - 1)
               LongDescWrapped_dt_extra.Add(cnk);
         else
               LongDescWrapped_dt.Add(cnk);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify with a bit more detail, i.e. code.  Are you using HTMLWriter?

Comment: No, I'm not using it. 
I have to print a description field that contains portions of text closed by tag <U>.......</>. I want to print that text underlined. So my question is:
iTextSharp could read this text and write underlined? Or Do I have to write some custom code?

Comment: If it is HTML, then it would be <U> </U>.  I have used IText and PDFSharp and what I have read, you can use the HTMLWriter to parse the HTML.  and <U></U> would be valid and not <U></>.  Alternatively, you could try a style for the whole element (div, p, etc.)

Comment: Dear @AnthonyHorne, you are talking about `HTMLWriter` when you actually mean to say `HTMLWorker`. You shouldn't advise people to use `HTMLWorker` because that class has been abandoned in favor of XML Worker. It is no longer supported (nor is `HtmlWriter` for that matter). Also: the OP is talking about filling out form field. In that case, your comment isn't helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordinary text fields do not support rich text. If you want the fields to remain interactive, you will need RichText fields. These are fields that are flagged in a way that they accept an `RV` value. This is explained here: [Set different parts of a form field to have different fonts using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410895/set-different-parts-of-a-form-field-to-have-different-fonts-using-itextsharp) (Note that I didn't succeed in getting this to work, but you may have better luck.)

If it is OK for you to flatten the form (i.e. remove all interactivity), please take a look at the [FillWithUnderline](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/FillWithUnderline) example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    FieldPosition pos = form.getFieldPositions("Name").get(0);
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(pos.page));
    ct.setSimpleColumn(pos.position);
    ElementList elements = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList("<div>Bruno <u>Lowagie</u></div>", null);
    for (Element element : elements) {
        ct.addElement(element);
    }
    ct.go();
    stamper.close();
}
```

In this example, we don't fill out the field, but we get the fields position (a page number and a rectangle). We then use `ColumnText` to add content at this position. As we are inputting HTML, we use XML Worker to parse the HTML into iText objects that we can add to the `ColumnText` object.

This is a Java example, but it should be easy to port this to C# if you know how to code in C# (which I don't).

Comment: Yes! This approch seems to work. I have some issues on Text style, but it works! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can trythis

```
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Underlined TExt", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12.0f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD | iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE));
            Paragraph reportHeadline = new Paragraph(chunk);
            reportHeadline.SpacingBefore = 12.0f;
            pdfDoc.Add(reportHeadline);
```

Comment: I was looking to add underline and bold to the text and the | works.