# Change AcroFields order in existing PDF with iText?

Tags: pdf, itext, formfield, acrofields

I have a pdf with text form fields at are layered one on top of the other. When I fill the fields via iText and flatten the form, the form field that I had created on top of the other form field is now on the bottom.

For instance, I have a text field named "number_field" and that is underneath a second text field that is titled "name_field". When I set the value for those fields via iText (so 10 for number_field and 'John' for name_field), the number_field is now on top of the name_field.

How do I change the order on the page of these fields with iText? Is it possible?

Link to example PDF: https://freecompany.sharefile.com/d-s84f6d63e7d04fe79

Comment: Do you have a PDF with overlapping fields. The order of the fields is usually determined by the order they appear in the `/Fields` array (unless defined otherwise), and there's certainly a way to tweak this. But to be sure (and to be able to write a POC), I'd need a PDF that helps me reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: Yes, it is a PDF with overlapping fields. The editing the order of the /Fields array sounds just like what I need. Do you want me to upload and link an example or send you the specific pdf I'm working with?

Comment: Updating your question by providing a link would be great.

Comment: Using an alternative way to fill out the form could solve your problem immediately. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579382/underline-portion-of-text-using-itextsharp). In the answer, I suggest to get the position of the fields using `getFieldPositions()`, then I add content using `ColumnText`. Since the names of your fields are quite predictable `day_x` and `day_x_notes`, you could make sure that you add the notes on top of the days (or vice-versa depending on what you want). That way, you don't need to fix the order of the fields.

Comment: I've discovered that iText stores the fields in a `HashMap`, so there is no way to predict the order. Based on an experiment, I think that Adobe Reader uses the position of the field to sort them. Other options to sort fields would be the order in the `/Fields` array, but a more logical order would be the order in which the widget annotations appear in the `/Annots` array on a page. Given the fact that there are so many options to sort fields, I suggest that you use the alternative as described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made the following ticket in the issue tracker at iText Group:

> A problem is caused by the fact that iText reads the field items into
>   a `HashMap`, hence there is no way to predict in which order they will
>   be flattened. This usually isn't a problem. I don't think this problem
>   occurs in case you don't flatten the PDF, because in that case, the
>   appearance is stored in the widget annotations and it's up to the PDF
>   viewer to decide which field covers another one in case of overlapping
>   fields.
>
> However, if form fields overlap, then you can't predict which field
>   will cover which when flattening.
>
> Suppose that we'd use a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap`, would this
>   solve the problem? Not really, because which `Comparator` would we
>   use? Sometimes a Tab-order is defined, but not always. If it's not
>   defined, should we order the fields in the order in which they appear
>   in the `/Fields` array? Or does it make more sense to order them based
>   on the order of the widget annotations in the `/Annots` array? Another
>   option is to order them based on their position on the page. In short:
>   this is not a decision iText should make.
>
> However, if somebody would like to solve this problem, we could create
>   a `Comparator` member variable for `PdfStamperImp`. If such a
>   `Comparator` is provided (we could even provide some implementations),
>   then the flattening process would be executed in the order defined by
>   the `Comparator`.

This ticket has received a very low priority (I assume that you're not a customer of one of the iText Software companies), but while writing this ticket, I had another idea.

I already referred to [underline portion of text using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579382/underline-portion-of-text-using-itextsharp) in the comments. In this case, you'd get all the field positions (using the `getFieldPositions()` method) and draw all the contents in the right order using `ColumnText`. This approach has several disadvantages: in order for the font, font size, font color to be correct, you'd have to examine the fields. That requires some programming.

I am now posting this as an answer, because I have a much better alternative: fill out the form in two passes! This is shown in the [FillFormFieldOrder](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/FillFormFieldOrder) example. We fill out the form `src` resulting in the flattened form `dest` like this:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    go2(go1(src), dest);
}
```

As you can see, we execute the `go1()` method first:

```
public byte[] go1(String src) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    form.setField("sunday_1", "1");
    form.setField("sunday_2", "2");
    form.setField("sunday_3", "3");
    form.setField("sunday_4", "4");
    form.setField("sunday_5", "5");
    form.setField("sunday_6", "6");
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.partialFormFlattening("sunday_1");
    stamper.partialFormFlattening("sunday_2");
    stamper.partialFormFlattening("sunday_3");
    stamper.partialFormFlattening("sunday_4");
    stamper.partialFormFlattening("sunday_5");
    stamper.partialFormFlattening("sunday_6");
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

This fills out all the `sunday_x` fields and uses partial form flattening to flatten *only those fields*. The `go1()` method takes `src` as parameter and returns a `byte[]` will the partially flattened form.

The `byte[]` will be used as a parameter for the `go2()` method, that takes `dest` as its second parameter. Now we are going to fill out the `sunday_x_notes` fields:

```
public void go2(byte[] src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    form.setField("sunday_1_notes", "It's Sunday today, let's go to the sea");
    form.setField("sunday_2_notes", "It's Sunday today, let's go to the park");
    form.setField("sunday_3_notes", "It's Sunday today, let's go to the beach");
    form.setField("sunday_4_notes", "It's Sunday today, let's go to the woods");
    form.setField("sunday_5_notes", "It's Sunday today, let's go to the lake");
    form.setField("sunday_6_notes", "It's Sunday today, let's go to the river");
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

As you can see, we now flatten all the fields. The result looks like [this](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/calendar_filled.pdf):

[image]

Now, you no longer have to worry about the order of the fields, not in the `/Fields` array, not in the `/Annots` array. The fields are filled out in the exact order you want to. The notes cover the dates now, instead of the other way round.

Comment: makes sense to rethink the actual requirement... ;)