# iTextPdf HTML to PDF : how to render HTML at specific location in PDF

Tags: java, html, css, itextpdf, html-to-pdf

I have below HTML string :

```
<font size="5">Requirements:</font><br><ul><li>Bullets are helpful</li><li>to display key points</li></ul><br>
```

How can I render above HTML into PDF at specific location?

I have checked some examples at http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker but no where mentioned about this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825782/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itext This does not answer my question, I need to put HTML styled text to specific location in PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't a duplicate, but it is related to these questions:

- [underline portion of text using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579382/underline-portion-of-text-using-itextsharp)
- [How to adjust the page height to the content height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186661/adjust-page-height-to-content-height)

In both cases, we parse the HTML to an `ElementList`:

```
ElementList elements = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(HTML, CSS);
```

We then create a `ColumnText` object `ct` to which we add the elements:

```
for (Element element : elements) {
    ct.addElement(element);
}
ct.go();
```

In the first question, the *specific location* is determined by the position of an AcroForm form field:

```
FieldPosition pos = form.getFieldPositions("Name").get(0);
```

We create a `ColumnText` object like this:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamper.getOverContent(pos.page));
ct.setSimpleColumn(pos.position);
```

You'll have to do something similar if you want to render the HTML to an existing PDF.

The second example is somewhat awkward because we use the `ColumnText` to determine the height of the page. However, the principle is similar:

```
ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(120, 600, 240, 800));
ct.go();
```

In this case, I hard-coded the coordinates of the absolute position. It's a rectangle with lower-left corner x=120;y=600 and upper-right corner x=240;y=800.

Comment: Thanks Bruno :) first solution which is ElementList is worked for me. I will test my code and will answer to this post.

Comment: How to Render Html As Pdf? Like a entire HTML String to PDF?