# Get acrofields font from pdf using Itextsharp

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf

I need to get the Font information, name and size from a specific field in the pdf form. In the pdf there are more fields with the same name and different Font and I don't want to edit the pdf field's names. I'm using Itexsharp. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set different parts of a form field to have different fonts using iTextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410895/set-different-parts-of-a-form-field-to-have-different-fonts-using-itextsharp)

Comment: I don't think that's the answer

Comment: *more fields with the same name* - a PDF only contains one field with a given name. That field may have multiple widgets. By definition, though, they all have the same value (even though it may appear differently if the widgets have differing appearance streams).

Answer (score 1):

I solved, It works like this:

```
Private Sub FieldsFontProperties(ByVal Path As String)
    Dim Reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(Path)
    Dim Fields As AcroFields = Reader.AcroFields

    For Each Field In Fields.Fields
        Dim Item As AcroFields.Item = Fields.GetFieldItem(Field.Key)
        Dim TextField As TextField = New TextField(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
        Fields.DecodeGenericDictionary(Item.GetMerged(0), TextField)
        Dim t As String()() = TextField.Font.FullFontName

        Dim FontName As String = t(0)(3)
        Dim FontSize As Single = TextField.FontSize
    Next
End Sub
```